# How to get report for a particluar group of pages in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking to get report for a particular group of pages in Google Analytics but couldn't find how to deal with it?

Can anyone help me how to do so, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: You could use the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) and request the [dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking) `ga:pagepath` and use a [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) for `ga:pagePath==/my/group/`.

Comment: @Matt thanks man for your time, I am newbie. Can you tell me how and where should I do it? Thanks again

Comment: Play around with the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) It will give you a sense of what is possible with the API. And once you are ready take a look at the [Quickstart guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/#next)

Comment: Looking forward, you could configure Content Groupings to group specific and relevant pages together so that you don't need to do any special filtering when viewing activity for a fixed group of pages.

Comment: @nyuen Thanks buddy but I tried for content grouping but didn't succeed. I didn't get about "Define Rules" in google analytics. Can you share screenshots? Thanks